# How to change spelllang alias in vim-airline (option `vim.g.airline_detect_spelllang = 1`)?

Tags: neovim, spell-checking, lua, plugin-airline, spelling

I have enabled the `vim.g.airline_detect_spell = 1` and `vim.g.airline_detect_spelllang = 1` options (config is written in Lua and can be found [here](https://github.com/Dolfost/dotfiles/tree/main/nvim)). The `vim.g.airline_detect_spelllang = 1` makes the vim-airline to show current spell langs after the MODE in brackets.

[image]

How I can make the UK print as UA, EN_US print as EN and RU_RU print as RU? Can I remove the brackets? Can I replace the separator / with something else? Is there some workaround?

Comment: this comes from your 'spelllang' setting and looks like this is hard-coded (you can use try the flags value however.